# How to compare the value of a column with multiple other column values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which stores an Annual Value as well as a Value for each Calendar Month (January through December).

I would like to easily check the value in all 12 month columns and determine whether or not the values between each of the months is the same.  Each of the value columns defined as `INT` and can contain NULL values.

What is the easiest way to compare these columns in a `SELECT`?

```
CREATE TABLE #FOO
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    YearlyValue INT NULL,
    JanValue INT NULL,
    FebValue INT NULL,
    MarValue INT NULL,
    AprValue INT NULL,
    MayValue INT NULL,
    JunValue INT NULL,
    JulValue INT NULL,
    AugValue INT NULL,
    SepValue INT NULL,
    OctValue INT NULL,
    NovValue INT NULL,
    DecValue INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #FOO (YearlyValue, JanValue, FebValue, MarValue, AprValue, MayValue, JunValue, JulValue, AugValue, SepValue, OctValue, NovValue, DecValue)
VALUES (NULL, 19, 19, 19, 19, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16)
     , (5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
     , (NULL, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5)
;

SELECT * FROM #FOO

DROP TABLE #FOO;
```

**EDIT**
This appears to be working well for what I'm trying to do.  Thanks to user `MuthuMK`, and everyone else for your assistance.

```
SELECT D.ID, MIN(A) AS MinValue, MAX(A) AS MaxValue
FROM #FOO AS D
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES (D.JanValue), (D.FebValue), (D.MarValue), (D.AprValue), (D.MayValue)
         , (D.JunValue), (D.JulValue), (D.AugValue), (D.SepValue), (D.OctValue)
         , (D.NovValue), (D.DecValue)
) AS X(A)
GROUP BY D.ID
HAVING MIN(A) = MAX(A)
```

Comment: Could you please show sampled data and expected result

Comment: Are you just trying to see if they are the same? As in, are you just looking for a yes/no answer, or do you need to know which columns have the same values?

Comment: If you are only trying to get a yes/no to "Are they all the same", take a union by row, the size of the array would tell you how many unique values there are (1 implies they are all the same)

Comment: @Jackson Yes, I am trying to determine on `SELECT` whether all 12 or 13 columns contain the same value or not.

Comment: @TheGameiswar I have updated the post.

Comment: Please check this link and see how you can improve the question..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Do you care what the value is? Or just that they all match or all don't match?

Comment: @Jackson Just that they they are all the same, or not the same.

Comment: Let me know if my answer is accomplishing the task, seems like the easiest way to me, though not necessarily the best

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check this for each new insertion, I suggest having trigger is the best way.having the trigger which inform you each and every new row which includes 
different values for 12 months. If it is for existing data stored procedure would be the easiest way.

Comment: Yes, this work for inserting into the DB.  However, your response indicated I was not clear enough on my question.  I have updated it to reflect that I am looking to do this via `SELECT`.

Comment: Try this one http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104521/compare-4-or-more-columns-values. Cross apply.

Answer (score 1):

```
where JanValue = FebValue
  and JanValue = MarValue  
  and JanValue = AprValue   
...
```

any null will return false

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE JanValue = FebValue = MarValue = ... = DecValue`

This returns all rows where Jan-Dec are the same.

Not sure what the goal is exactly still, but you could take it a step further and turn it into an `UPDATE` instead, changing the `AnnualValue` for rows where all 12 month columns are the same:

`UPDATE table SET AnnualValue = JanValue WHERE JanValue = FebValue = MarValue = ... = DecValue`

Comment: Unfortunately, SQL Server does not like the `column = column = column` syntax.  The management of the `AnnualValue` column has already been taken care of.  I am attempting to simply verify that the data is good using `SELECT` statements.

Comment: How about `columnA = columnB and columnA = columnC`?

Comment: Or do you mean that SQL Server doesn't take `column = column` type-wise

Comment: You could also declare a variable equal to `JanValue` and compare to that variable if SQL Server accepts that